# Rx Framework for parallel webservice calls

Tags: parallel-processing, system.reactive

Can I use Rx framework to run multiple process simultaneous without blocking UI ?
Suppose I want to make calls to different webservices [may be 1000 or more] at the same time from my WPF UI. and the results of each web service call, i need to update it to the grid in the UI. I done it using Task and Parallel. But when i start the process, Parallel foreach is starting with few services calls only out of 1000. first time, it takes 15 or 20, after some it calls next 20 or 15, etc. So this is not what I want. All the 1000 calls should happen at the same time and each calls should take care of its results and updating back to the grid !!

Such type of operation is possible using RX framework ? If yes, can provide any guidlines in this matter ?? I am a newbie in RX.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to take a look at ForkJoin method: http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc3. It's in the Rx Experimental.

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite easy to do what you want.

Here's an example of how the query should be structured:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Range(0, 100)
    from t in webServiceCall(n)
    select new { n, t };
```

The `webServiceCall` function has this signature: `Func<int, IObservable<string>>`.

I tested the above using:

```
Func<int, IObservable<string>> webServiceCall =
    n =>
        Observable
            .Return(n.ToString() + "!")
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
```

... and with this subscription:

```
query.ToArray().Subscribe(results =>
{
    /* array of results here */
});
```

I got all of the results back in just over a second.

I did try this with `Observable.Range(0, 1000)` and got an out of memory error in LinqPad so you might need to watch for your limit in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you elaborate the webserviceCall method for better understanding ? Suppose I have a collection of 1000 records in the WPF UI data grid. Each record has to update its own status in the WPF UI data grid after calling the webservice.

Comment: @Soonils - Well, in my example code `n` would be the index of each record and when you call the web service the return result would be `t` (whatever type that the web service returns). The `n` & `t` get paired up, i.e. `new { n, t }`, so that you know which record has which status. If you don't mind updating the results as they come in then remove the `.ToArray()` and you can handle each pair one at a time.

Comment: Hi again thanks for the reply. I understood what you are saying. Usually what we do is, we make wcf calls from wpf and wcf has callback functionalities. When service do the some lengthy process, it fires back each process status thru callbacks until the process completes. So we can update the status of each process in the UI using callbacks [ie, fring events from service]. Can we do the same thing without implementing callbacks in our WCF using Rx ? Wow thats Great !!! Could you please throw some light on it...And in ur example, how i can update the UI in the subscribe part ?? Thanks very much